# i2c and Linux (127 devices and i2cdetect question)

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, i2c

[Update: This is wrong]It seems that with the i2cdetect program in Linux, it only scans addresses from 0 to 7f, while you technically can have 127 devices on the bus (0 to FF).[End of Wrong]

Furthermore, I've found that for an address that you might expect at 0x22 shows up as 0x11 in the program.  This suggests that the i2cdetect program is bit shifting the address and ignoring the least significant bit.

However, the device tree also seems to require the 0x11 address in the tree versus the expect 0x22 address.   I.e. my device is not recognized unless I put the bit shifted address. I do not have a long past history with linux and hardware drivers, so I'm wondering if this is expected behavior?  E.g. I'm looking at the PCA9655 I/O Expander.

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/pca9655e-d.pdf

Thanks,

Comment: but 127 == 0x7F

Comment: Ok yea - that is true.  So I'm guessing this is normal.  If the datasheet says 0x22 that's with a 0 in the LSB, the address you put in Linux is 0x11

Comment: the R/W bit is not considered to be part of the adress. Your datasheet probably refers to two different adresses 0x22 and 0x23 but this should be 0x11.